# $2^x+2^{-x} = 5$, solve $4^x+4^{-x}$ using the rules of exponents

Tags: calculus

> $2^x+2^{-x} = 5$
>
> Solve:
>
> $4^x+4^{-x}$

I know I can solve this by solving the equation $2^x+2^{-x} = 5$ and then replacing $x$ on the second one with the result, but I found that to be too lengthy and overcomplicated.

Is there a faster and simpler way of solving this using some rules?

The solution is $4^x+4^{-x} = 23$

Comment: What happens if you square your equation?

Comment: @BobJones it becomes $(2^x)^2+(2^{-x})^2 = $... $25$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$4^x+4^{-x}=2^{2x}+2^{-2x}=(2^x+2^{-x})^2-2\cdot 2^x \cdot 2^{-x}=25-2=23$

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd step. Could you explain to me why (and how) $2^{2x}+2^{-2x}$ becomes $(2^x+2^{-x})^2-2\cdot 2^x \cdot 2^{-x}$?

Comment: @AliceIsDead : $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2\cdot a \cdot b \Rightarrow a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2\cdot a \cdot b$

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying